# search for a word in an array of cells containing sentences in excel

Tags: excel, nlp, substring

I want to search for a word in an array of cells containing sentences. Is there some way to return the value of the matching cell (or at least its position)?

For example:

The word: "banana"

The array: A1="I love apples" A2="I hate bananas"

My result should be "I hate bananas"

Hope its understandable

Comment: just in excel @brett

Answer (score 3):

What's this new fad using Aggregate for everything these days? This Index/Match does the same thing:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*bananas*",A:A,0))
```

And for only the row number

```
=MATCH("*bananas*",A:A,0)
```

Only the first match will be returned.

Comment: The search was for "banana" not "banana*s*".  small typo.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that sometimes the simple is the best.  I went into more detail [HERE](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111528/vba-lounge)

Answer (score 1):

### Excel solution

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",$A$1:$A$2)),1)-0)
```

The -0 is there for number or header row you have.  in your case it was no header rows, so -0.  If you had two header rows then it would have been -2

In the event of multiple sentences with banana, the above formula will return the first sentence where what you are searching for it found.  To find the last sentence where the searched word is found change the 15 to 14.

To know the position (ie what row number it is in) you would drop the index portion and use:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",$A$1:$A$2)),1)
```

To know what position in your array it is in case you have header rows or your started some point in the middle of your sheet you would need to subtract the rows above your starting cell and your formula could look like this:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$2)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH("banana",$A$1:$A$2)),1)-(ROW($A$1)-1)
```

Comment: And if I wanted to know the position?

Comment: Can you explain the reason for AGGREGATE? Why over-complicate things with this convoluted function? What's wrong with a simple MATCH instead?

Comment: @teylyn nothing wrong with match.  AGGREGATE was the first solution that popped in my head that I could make do a search without using a CSE formula.  It also allows for a simple switch from first row to last row.  I prefer the answer you have though